# Take data from Mysql for telegram bot

Tags: php, mysql, heroku, telegram-bot

I'm tryng to write my first telegram bot fo my restaurant to make automatic reservation and check the daily menu. I use heroku PHP for the app, mysql on Aruba webserver, so i write:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$content = file_get_contents("php://input");
$update = json_decode($content, true);

$link = mysqli_connect('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');
$query =  "SELECT * FROM quinto_menu_day ORDER BY ORDINE ASC" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link));
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query); 
$rows = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  $rows[] = array(
  'tipo' => $row['TIPO'],
  'piatto' => $row['PIATTO']
);
}
$menu = json_encode($rows);
$message = isset($update['message']) ? $update['message'] : "";
$messageId = isset($message['message_id']) ? $message['message_id'] : "";
$chatId = isset($message['chat']['id']) ? $message['chat']['id'] : "";
$firstname = isset($message['chat']['first_name']) ? $message['chat']['first_name'] : "";
$lastname = isset($message['chat']['last_name']) ? $message['chat']['last_name'] : "";
$username = isset($message['chat']['username']) ? $message['chat']['username'] : "";
$date = isset($message['date']) ? $message['date'] : "";
$text = isset($message['text']) ? $message['text'] : "";
$text = trim($text);
$text = strtolower($text);
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$response = '';
$menu = $row['schedule'];
if(strpos($text, "/start") === 0 || $text=="ciao")
{
    $response = "Salve $firstname $lastname, benvenuto sul bot del Quinto Quarto! Scrivi prenotazione per prenotare un tavolo, oppure menu per conoscere il menu di oggi!";
}
elseif($text=="prenotazione")
{
    $response = "Per quante persone vuoi prenotare il giorno $date?";
}
elseif($text=="menu")
{
    $response = "menu del giorno: $menu";
}
else
{
    $response = "Comando non valido!";
}
$parameters = array('chat_id' => $chatId, "text" => $response);
$parameters["method"] = "sendMessage";
echo json_encode($parameters);
```

The problem is that with the MYSQL part the script dont work, but if I remove, the script work fine!
Where is the problem? Is it possible use Mysql with telegram bot?

Comment: It is absolutely possible to use MysSQL for a Telegram bot. Do you have a error message?

Comment: no error! I open the bot write msg, for example "ciao" and nothing happen! If I remove MYSQL part, all work right, so if I write "ciao" the bot give $response right! Is it possible that with Heroku I can't connect to my DB on other server?

Comment: Yes, maybe you should add an `or die` statement to the `mysqli_connect` line.

Comment: take a look is there $query =  "SELECT * FROM quinto_menu_day ORDER BY ORDINE ASC" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link));

Comment: You have to put the `or die` statements next to the function calls, like `mysqli_connect` or `mysql_execute`. Like that: `mysqli_connect('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx') or die("Error connecting")`